# Remove video when it is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am looking to have a video start when a page loads, but once the video has completed, to hide the video (remove the layer possibly). I saw it on a yoga site a few years ago where a video message from the owner appeared over top the content when the page loaded but then dissapeared after the video was done. Not even sure where to begin looking for something like this.

Comment: What type of Video is it - Flash? Silverlight? HTML5?

Comment: I don't know any specific products, but you should look for a video player that has JavaScript hooks for events like start, pause, end.

Comment: It's live video thats been shot and edited, it can be exported out to any format.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that needs to be handled at the player level. Many flash players or frameworks allow you to register for an event. One event might be on video complete. First get this working. You may not be able to do this from javascript. For example, adobe's strobe player requires you to write a swf plugin which would be loaded in the flash player. Not trivial.

After you have registered it, you can easily close the window by executing some javascript function.

Let me know if you have more questions.